# Invariant rank-3 Cartesian Tensors

Tags: multivariable-calculus, tensors

I recently came across the question,

"Evaluate the integral $$ \int r^{-5} e^{- \gamma r^2} x_i x_j x_k dV , \gamma >0, r^2=x_p x_p $$ over all of space".

Under a change of orthonormal basis (say in $ \mathbb{R} ^3 $), $r$ is invariant hence the integral is a rank-3 isotropic tensor, i.e. is $ \lambda \epsilon _{ijk} $ for some constant lambda.

But $\epsilon _{ijk} $ is antisymmetric in 2 indices, but our integral tensor is symmetric (since changing two indices is effectively an orthonormal base change), so I must conclude that $$ \int r^{-5} e^{- \gamma r^2} x_i x_j x_k dV = 0 $$

However this seems a little strange, since this seems to apply for the general case of $$ \int f(\mathbf{x}) x_i x_j x_k dV$$ where $f(\mathbf{x})$ is invariant under ortho. basis change.

So my above reasoning would say any such integral would be 0.

**Is this correct? Are there any general results about such integrals?**